# Find words with the same vowel separated with a consonant

Tags: grep

I'm looking for a grep argument to find in a text words that have the pattern vowel-consonant-samevowel.

Examples:

**oro**
**ene**ro
f**ofo**
pppp**epe**pppp

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that what constitutes a vowel varies with language and region.

For the commonly admitted English vowels (here only considering the lower case versions):

```
vowels=aeiou
consonants=bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz

grep "\([$vowels]\)[$consonants]\1"
```

You can adapt `$vowels` and `$consonants` to your language.

However with Unicode, it can get a little more complicated.

For instance, even if we restrict to the latin script, in French, that would match on the word for summer: été. In Unicode however, that é can be written as a single character (U+00E9 `é`) or in a decomposed form with `e` followed by its *combining* acute accent (`◌́` U+0301).

Also, there are characters like `ﬁ` that are another way to write 2 characters `fi`.

One way to address that is to convert the text into [a normalized form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization) where those are expanded into their multi-character form before checking (and we then need to consider base characters and their sequence of diacritics or other combining characters (the full graphem cluster like `e⃞` != `é̂`).

```
perl -MUnicode::Normalize -C -lne '
  print if NFKD($_) =~ /((?=[aeiouy])\X)(?=[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz])\X\1(?!\p{mark})/'
```

(NKFD is the normalisation form with *compatibility decomposition*, the one that turns `é` into `e` + `◌́` and `ﬁ` into `f` + `i`).

`\X` in `perl` matches an *extended graphem cluster*. So `(?=[aeiouy])\X` is a graphem cluster whose base character is a lowercase latin vowel (so `e` or `é`...). Here including `y` as a vowel (since it's considered as such in many languages using the latin script).

So we match on a vowel cluster followed by a consonant cluster followed by the first cluster as captured in `\1`, but we need to make sure the next character is not still part of the cluster, otherwise it would match in things like `eté`. Hence the negative look-ahead operator to check that the next character is not one with the `mark` property.

So, on an input like:

```
ﬁni
été
tacheté
```

It returns:

```
ﬁni
été
```